# data not found but it is in the environment, document won't knit

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to knit my document to check everything looks okay, but keep getting the error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'MSTData' not found
>
> Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval
>
> Execution halted

However the object is in the enviroment so I am not sure why it isn't working?

- Tried knitting the document
- Tried renaming the data as it was a longer name, but still not working.

The code runs fine, just having an issue with knitting. When I run the chunks with the data it analyses the info from the file just fine?

Here is the code:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
```

*filtering participant data*

```
#renaming MST data to shorten 
Filtered <- dplyr::select(MSTData, Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14) 
#started with 45 participants, down to 41 after filtering out NA values
Filtered <- na.omit(Filtered)

Filtered
```

*filtering trail making data*

```
Trail <- dplyr::select(TM_FC, subject, group, trail1Time, trail2Time) %>%  dplyr::filter(subject != 208) 
#Filtered out unnecessary columns not needed for analysis
#removed participant 208 as no data recorded for Trail B
Trail


trail_fin <- Trail |> 
  dplyr::filter(group == 2) 
#filtered out to only have the final times taken for each trail to calulate final time 

trail_fin

trail_fin <- trail_fin |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
        BminusA = trail2Time-trail1Time
  )
trail_fin

208
```

*FAS Data*

```
FAS <- dplyr::select(FAS_Counted, subject, response, ...19)
#need to figure out how to rename column for exact word count!

FAS
```

Comment: Can you share your code and data? it's hard to say what the problem is without knowing more

Comment: One possibility is that you are using relative paths to load your data, and the environment where your document is being knitted (based on where your file is stored) is different from your working directory when you are running your code in chunks. But as Russ mentioned, we can only hazard guesses without seeing anything more than your error message.

Comment: Knitting always starts from a clean environment, meaning that all data imports  and further processing must be handled by the document itself. By default RStudio automatically saves and restores workspace for you when you exit and start the program and this can make it seems like everything that gets added to the environment will remain there until it's explicitly removed,  but that restored environment state is not available for knit.

Comment: Where's the bit that actually loads dataset and assigns MSTData? If you imported your dataset through RStudio UI, you must add the import code also to your document to be able to knit.

Comment: @Russ I have updated the post to show the full code; the error is occurring within the 'filtering participant data' chunk; the object 'MSTData' is supposedly not found, even though it is in the environment and as said when I just run the chunk, the code works fine. The issue is only occurring when trying to knit.

Not sure if it is relevant, but I am also on the cloud version of RStudio (PositCloud) in order to work between devices, so all files are from a google drive equivalent.

Comment: @margusl the section that is accessing the data where the error is occurring is under 'filtering participant data'. Not sure what you mean exactly by the rest of your comment, sorry.

Comment: That Posit cloud thing might be relevant. How are you loading MSTData? Could you also add the result from this `dput(head(MSTData))` to the question?

Comment: Issue is not in the section that triggers the error but where you load your dataset (which seems to be missing). What objects you have in your current interactive environment doesn't affect knitting as knitting process starts from a clean environment and you must explicitly load the dataset (e.g. read.csv / read_csv & friends ) in your script, otherwise the the MSTData object simply doesn't exist for knit.

Comment: @Russ the output is too long to add to the question cause the data is a very large file. Not sure how I can show it to you

Comment: @margusl ah okay i see what you mean. I attempted to read_csv the dataset at the top of the chunk, but still having the same issue?

Comment: include a sample with the first few results `dput(head(MSTData, 10))`

Comment: @Russ I have no clue how, but the knitting has somehow started working. Thank you so much for your help though!